# Polite alternatives to "That's none of your business"

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language, politeness

I'm looking for a more polite alternative to "That's none of your business".

Would "That doesn't concern you." and "That's none of your concern." be more polite? Would they be idiomatic as well, or is "concern" formal in spoken English?

Comment: It's true that "concern" is less casual (or maybe it's just more common to British usage?), but that doesn't make it more polite.

Comment: Instead of focusing on *them*, emphasise it's *yours* (your private/personal issue/business/matter)

Answer (score 5):

The alternatives you posted are not very polite.

The most common polite version is "I'd rather not say."

Answer (score 1):

Another reasonably polite phrase you could use is "no comment".

Answer (score 0):

“I would prefer not to discuss that” or “I would prefer not to speak about that” should suffice in most situations. The phrase “That’s none of your concern” is more formal, but conveys an equally impolite tone.